# GradientTape losing track of variable

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a script that performs a Gatys-like neural style transfer. It uses style loss, and a total variation loss. I'm using the GradientTape() to compute my gradients. The losses that I have implemented seem to work fine, but a new loss that I added isn't being properly accounted for by the GradientTape(). I'm using TensorFlow with eager execution enabled.

I suspect it has something to do with how I compute the loss based on the input variable. The input is a 4D tensor (batch, h, w, channels). At the most basic level, the input is a floating point image, and in order to compute this new loss I need to convert it to a binary image to compute the ratio of one pixel color to another. I don't want to actually go and change the image like that during every iteration, so I just make a copy of the tensor(in numpy form) and operate on that to compute the loss. I do not understand the limitations of the GradientTape, but I believe it is "losing the thread" of how the input variable is used to get to the loss when it's converted to a numpy array.

Could I make a copy of the image tensor and perform binarizing operations & loss computation using that? Or am I asking tensorflow to do something that it just can not do?

My new loss function:

```
def compute_loss(self, **kwargs):
   loss = 0
   image = self.model.deprocess_image(kwargs['image'].numpy())
   binarized_image = self.image_decoder.binarize_image(image)
   volume_fraction = self.compute_volume_fraction(binarized_image)
   loss = np.abs(self.volume_fraction_target - volume_fraction)
   return loss
```

My implementation using the GradientTape:

```
def compute_grads_and_losses(self, style_transfer_state):
        """
        Computes gradients with respect to input image
        """
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self.loss_evaluator.compute_total_loss(style_transfer_state)
        total_loss = loss['total_loss']
        return tape.gradient(total_loss, style_transfer_state['image']), loss
```

An example that I believe might illustrate my confusion. The strangest thing is that my code doesn't have any problem running; it just doesn't seem to minimize the new loss term whatsoever. But this example won't even run due to an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute '_id'`.

Example:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import tensorflow as tf

def compute_square_of_value(x):
    a = turn_to_numpy(x['x'])
    return a**2

def turn_to_numpy(arg):
    return arg.numpy() #just return arg to eliminate the error

tf.enable_eager_execution()
x = tfe.Variable(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
data_dict = {'x': x}
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  tape.watch(x)
  y = compute_square_of_value(data_dict)

dy_dx = tape.gradient(y, x) # Will compute to 6.0

print(dy_dx)
```

Edit:

From my current understanding the issue arises that my use of the .numpy() operation is what makes the Gradient Tape lose track of the variable to compute the gradient from. My original reason for doing this is because my loss operation requires me to physically change values of the tensor, and I don't want to actually change the values used for the tensor that is being optimized. Hence the use of the numpy() copy to work on in order to compute the loss properly.  Is there any way around this? Or is shall I consider my loss calculation to be impossible to implement because of this constraint of having to perform essentially non-reversible operations on the input tensor?

Answer (score 2):

The first issue here is that GradientTape only traces operations on tf.Tensor objects. When you call tensor.numpy() the operations executed there fall outside the tape.

The second issue is that your first example never calls tape.watche on the image you want to differentiate with respect to.

Comment: Thank you @Alexandre. If I'm using the eager execution mode, would I still need to use the "watch"? My optimization seems to work just fine without using it(with the exception of this new loss of course).

Comment: Ok you've cut to the heart of my question. For this particular loss the tensor is an image(batch,H,W,C). In order to compute the loss I need to take the floating point values of the pixels in the image and map them to the closest value(say [0,0,0] and [255,255,255] for example) such that each pixel is either one value or another. Then I compute the ratio and that is the "volume fraction" loss that gets returned.  I don't want to actually mess with the original image that is being optimized, hence why I take just a copy in the form of a numpy array. Can you make tensor copies?

Comment: TF tensors are immutable, so there's no way you can mess with it and you don't need to make a copy. If you insist on making one, though, you can always just use tf.identity. However it doesn't look to me like your loss is differentiable (since infinitesimal changes in the value of the image pixels do not have any effect on the input)

Comment: I see. This is perplexing for me then because in order to evaluate the volume fraction loss I need to take a snapshot of the tensor that represents the generated image and perform image processing on the pixels to adjust them such that the loss calculation can be computed.  Changes in the input image would affect the loss because the volume fraction of Pixels A/ Pixels B would change (or at least that is what I think).